# JQuery Internal does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, internal

This is my javascript code

```
$(this).find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy)').on('click',function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        History.pushState(null, $(this).text(), $(this).attr('href'));
    });
```

and this is the link I am trying to not apply ajax on

```
 <a href="#loginModal" class="btn btn-success no-ajaxy" data-toggle="modal">Login &rsaquo;&rsaquo;</a>
```

The problem here is that my script gives me this error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: internal
```

I am currently using   jQuery v1.8.3

Comment: There is no `:internal` selector, so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to select all href tags that has a no-ajaxy in their class name

Comment: `$(this).find('a.no-ajaxy').on(...` Although what you're saying you want is the complete opposite of what your code appears to be trying to do.

Comment: will that work if the class name is something like class ="btn btns-submit no-ajaxy"  ?

Comment: Yes. It matches on individual classes, not all classes together - exactly the same as CSS does.

Comment: but what if I want to select contents who doesn't have the class no-ajaxy?

Comment: `$(this).find('a:not(.no-ajaxy)')` All of this is in the selectors section of http://api.jquery.com - I'd suggest you read it.

Comment: There it finally work! I wish I can pick you as best answer

Comment: I've added it as an answer if you want to accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, it sounds like you simply need to use the following:

```
$(this).find('a:not(.no-ajaxy)').on('click', function() {
     // your code...
});
```

`:internal` is not a selector available by default in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create your custom selectors (copy of http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.ch/2010/03/custom-jquery-selector-for-external-and.html):

```
jQuery.extend(  
  jQuery.expr[ ":" ],  
  {  
    /* 
      /:\/\// is simply looking for a protocol definition. 
      technically it would be better to check the domain 
      name of the link, but i always use relative links 
      for internal links. 
    */  

    external: function(obj, index, meta, stack)  
    {  
      return /:\/\//.test($(obj).attr("href"));  
    },  

    internal: function(obj, index, meta, stack)  
    {  
      return !/:\/\//.test($(obj).attr("href"));  
    }  
  }  
);
```